# How to disable eslint in vscode

Tags: eslint, vscode-extensions, eslintrc

I'm getting eslint errors in my vscode, but I don't remember installing eslint extension in my vscode.

I tried checking in file->settings->users->extension in vscode but I can't find eslint in there.
How do I turn it off, it's very irritating.  Any other alternative to turn it off?

[image: Eslint not present in extensions]

Comment: it's under linting I think

Comment: press ctrl+shift+x, it'll take you to the extensions you have installed, then disable eslint

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys but nothing worked.
What I did was just ran `npm uninstall eslint` and got rid of eslint errors

Answer (score 0):

In VS2022 disabling ESLint option is in Tools->Options->Text Editor->JavaScript/TypeScript:
[image]